# working with JSON data, trying to parse nested data

Tags: json

I just working with JSON data and am playing around with jQuery and Ajax requests. Pretty basic stuff, but here's my problem.

I have a basic data set which I was using for time tracking. I know how to parse the simple JSON data like this:

```
{
        "end" : "1/18/2011",
        "start" : "1/18/2011",
        "task" : "Code Review",
},
```

It's the more complicated stuff I'm trying to parse like this where I'm trying to pull the "time" data out.

```
  {
        "end" : "1/17/2011",
        "start" : "1/17/2011",
        "task" : "Exclusive Brands",
        "time" : {
           "analysis" : 4,
           "documentation" : 3,
           "meetings" : 2
        }
```

This is the code for the script I've been using to parse the simple data:

```
$(function() {
    $('.load').click(function(){
        $.getJSON("data.js",function(data){
            $.each(data.timesheet, function(i,data){
            var div_data ="<div class='box'>"+data.start+" "+data.task+"</div>";
            $(div_data).appendTo("#time-tracking");
                });
            }
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

My question is what's the format to parse the `time` data, or what's the best way to parse the information nested inside the `time` element?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JSON string will be parsed into an object. When parsed, the `time` is the key of one object. You could retrieve the value of this object through the dot operator (`.`).

```
data = JSON.parse('{"end":"1/17/2011", "start":"1/17/2011", "task":"Exclusive Brands", "time": {"analysis":4, "documentation":3, "meetings":2 } }')
// => obj
data.time.analysis
// => 4
```

In your case similarly you could use the `data.time.meetings` to access your data from remote server.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for - the data.time.analysis format.

Comment: i have the same kind of data. but i am not able to access it. I have pasted data here http://pastebin.com/BQ5GLq0C. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am terribly mistaken, since jquery already converted data into a javascript for you, you should be able to access time as if it was a javascript object like so:

```
var analysis = data.time.analysis;
var documentation =  data.time.documentation;
var meetings = data.time.meetings;
```

etc...

Comment: In another part of the app I'm building, I will use this format - thanks for your help as well.